# Non-renewable subscription: minimum subscription time & dynamic content

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have this iOS app with dynamic content 
and a new requirement that it should have short-time (bellow 7 days) subscriptions.

Since minimum subscription time for auto-renewable subscription is 7 days i guess i can only go with non-renewable subscriptions.

**Question:**

1. Is it okay to have non-renewable subscriptions for dynamic content? I'm confused by

   > "For static services or service access, you should use Non-Renewing
   >   Subscriptions."

   quote from iTunesConnect Developer Guide. My app provides dynamic, not static services.
2. Is there any requirement on minimum time i can set for a subscription? Like, can i set say 6 hours for a subscription? I can do anything of course, but Apple may not approve.

Comment: I would assume that non-renewable subscriptions are fine for dynamic content. The fine print you quoted reads `For static services OR service access...` Don't quote me on that though.

Comment: @Yawus that's what i guessed too but you can never be sure when it comes to Apple. I'll be able to answer this in a few days because i already submitted binary and it waits for review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple had no problem with using non-renewable subscriptions for dynamic content, nor with non-specified times of subscriptions.

Comment: `11.6 Content subscriptions using IAP must last a minimum of 7 days and be available to the user from all of their iOS devices`